# Does anyone know of a good SDK that can Write (an encode) MOV files on windows?

Tags: windows, sdk, quicktime

I'm trying to find a good SDK that can encode frames with quicktime into MOV container. i cannot find the quicktime sdk anymore. 
any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I Finally found the Quicktime for windows SDK buried deep in apple's developer web site, you have to sign in with apple id to find it.